# Python SQLite3 Trying to decrement a value

Tags: python, sqlite

First, I'm sorry if this is an absolute mess - this is my first time messing with sqlite3, and I'm still very amateur in python. Anyway, I'm making a D&D encounter tracker and thus far I can add, edit, and remove players/creatures from their own databases. Below is the button click function for when you click "Damage Target" I've successfully made the dropdowns work and added the box for entry of the damage taken, but I've hit a wall and I'm not sure what I need to do.

The error I am receiving is: NameError: name 'hp' is not defined. I had thought I defined that within the table, and the c.execute("""UPDATE players SET...) command would directly reference the hp of the target. How can I get this to function?

```
def damageButtonClick():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Damage Target")

    def submitPlayerDB():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("players.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        use = playerOIDList[playerList.index(var2.get())]
        c.execute("""UPDATE players SET
                        hp = :hp,
                        WHERE oid = :oid""", {
            'hp': hp()-damageBox,
            'oid': use
        })
        #log damage amount to present encounter/round to the specific player

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        update()
        destroy()
    def submitCreatureDB():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("creature.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        use = creatureOIDList[creatureList.index(var2.get())]
        c.execute("""UPDATE creatures SET
                        hp = :hp,
                        WHERE oid = :oid""", {
            'hp': hp() - damageBox,
            'oid': use
        })
        # log damage amount to present encounter/round to the specific player

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        update()
        destroy()


    def destroy():
        top.destroy()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("players.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM players")
    players = c.fetchall()
    playerList = []
    playerOIDList = []
    for player in players:
        playerList.append(player[0])
        playerOIDList.append(player[8])
    conn = sqlite3.connect("creatures.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM creatures")
    creatures = c.fetchall()
    creatureList = []
    creatureOIDList = []
    for creature in creatures:
        creatureList.append(creature[0])
        creatureOIDList.append(creature[8])
    preselection = ["Player", "Creature"]
    selection = ""
    def createSubmitPlayer():
        submit = Button(top, text="Submit", command = submitPlayerDB())
        submit.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=5, ipadx=100)
    def createSubmitCreature():
        submit = Button(top, text="Submit", command=submitCreatureDB())
        submit.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=5, ipadx=100)
    def playerDropdown():
        var2.set(playerList[0])
        dropDown2 = OptionMenu(top, var2, *playerList)
        dropDown2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        createSubmitPlayer()

    def creatureDropdown():
        var2.set(creatureList[0])
        dropDown2 = OptionMenu(top, var2, *creatureList)
        dropDown2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        createSubmitCreature()
    def Selection(self):
        selection = var.get()
        if selection == "Player":
            playerDropdown()
        elif selection == "Creature":
            creatureDropdown()

    damageLabel = Label(top, text="Insert Damage Number: ")
    damageLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)
    damageBox = Entry(top)
    damageBox.grid(row=5, column = 1)

    cancel = Button(top, text="Cancel", command=top.destroy)
    cancel.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=5, ipadx=100)
    var = StringVar()
    var2 = StringVar()
    var.set("Make a Selection")
    dropDown1 = OptionMenu(top, var, "Player", "Creature", command = Selection)
    dropDown1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    update()
```

Comment: I should have been a bit more clear, I know that 'hp': hp()-damageBox will not work, but I'm not even getting to that part. This is unfortunate because I plan on using this type of code several times in several different ways.

Comment: it would help immensely if you provided the actual traceback, since it includes vital information for being able to help you...

Comment: It's a really big code and most of it has nothing to do with this issue, should I just crop out the stuff that doesn't matter to the issue and post it in its entirety with the full error?

Comment: There is a page explaining how to create a minimal, reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

python complains about this `'hp': hp()-damageBox,` because there is not a function named `hp`.

To subtract from a column, sql syntax, that would be something like:

```
UPDATE player
set hp = hp - someNumber
WHERE .....
```

sqlite already has `hp` of the player, so the parameter to substitue would be `damageBox` giving python syntax like:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE players SET
                        hp = hp - :damageBox,
                        WHERE oid = :oid""", {
            'damageBox': damageBox,
            'oid': use
        })
```

Comment: This mostly did it. Should have been `c.execute("""UPDATE players SET
            hp = hp - :damageBox
            WHERE oid = :oid""", {
                'damageBox': damageBox.get(),
                'oid': use
                })`